# how to hide a url from address bar using .htacess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

i have been searching for this over all the internet but i had no luck. i found some answer but it was of no help

i don't how to use .htacess but i found this code

```
   RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite /foo/bar to /foo/bar.php
RewriteRule ^([^.?]+)$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

# Return 404 if original request is /foo/bar.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$" 
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]

# NOTE! FOR APACHE ON WINDOWS: Add [NC] to RewriteCond like this:
# RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$" [NC]
```

it seems to block the all the page except index

http://www.skymount.in/mega_menu.php?id=%27503732-u_submenuid%27 
this is the link
i want it to look like 
http://www.skymount.in/mega_menu.php 
or maybe 
http://www.skymount.in/mega_menu

please help

Answer (score 0):

The $1 means "use the first capture part of the original url". In order to capture a part of the original URL, you need to use a parenthesis to capture it in. Like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/mega_menu/(.*) /$1
```

This means "take anything that starts with /mega_menu/, then capture what follows and put that into the variable $1. Rewrite to just the $1 variable and append the original query string.

I hope it helps you!

Answer (score -1):

Use this as the whole `.htaccess` file content:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^mega_menu\.php$ mega_menu.php?id=%27503732-u_submenuid%27 [NC]
```

Comment: should i change whole .htaccess with those two lines or add them in my .htacces

Comment: the whole .htaccess

Comment: Check that http://www.skymount.in/mega_menu.php is showing the content of http://www.skymount.in/mega_menu.php?id=%27503732-u_submenuid%27

Comment: no nothing is showing u can check it live the website is online